# RSA Encryption Illegal Block Size Exception

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to make a chat with end-to-end encryption, but i get `javax.crypto. IllegalBlockSizeException` on this line `byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(decodedMessage);`

I get other person's public key with this:

```
CollectionReference userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users");

userCollection.whereEqualTo("userID", targetFriendID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {@Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {

        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult()) {

                User tempUser = doc.toObject(User.class);

                targetFriendSDK = tempUser.getSDK();

                String keyString = tempUser.getPublicKey();

                byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(keyString, Base64.NO_WRAP);

                try {

                    friendPublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));

                    dialog.cancel();

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(ChatRoom.this, "Error, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        } else {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(ChatRoom.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Decryption is done like this :

```
String encodedMessage = cloudMessage.getMessage();
Date date = cloudMessage.getDate();
tring senderID = cloudMessage.getSenderID();
String receivID = cloudMessage.getReceiverID();

int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

byte[] decodedMessage = Base64.decode(encodedMessage, Base64.NO_WRAP);

String finalMessage;

try {

    if (sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");

        OAEPParameterSpec sp = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, sp);

        byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(decodedMessage);

        finalMessage = new String(decryptedMessage);

    } else {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(decodedMessage);

        finalMessage = new String(decryptedMessage);

    }
```

And Encryption:

```
byte[] messageBytes = messageText.getBytes();

String encodedMessage;

try {

    if (targetFriendSDK >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");

        OAEPParameterSpec sp = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, friendPublicKey, sp);

        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(messageBytes);

        encodedMessage = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    } else {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, friendPublicKey);

        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(messageBytes);

        encodedMessage = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    }
```

I'm doing basically the same thing but with one user in another activity, and everything works, the only difference between those activities is that in this one i try to get other users' public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, looks like it was completely not where I was expecting it to be.

The problem actually was this line `if (targetFriendSDK >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` where i was checking other users' device Android Version in order to differentiate between encryption types i should use. I realised it always returned 0 because of problem with Firestore naming.

I created a `User` document parsing custom User class to create document, and one of the fields, the sdk field was named `private int SDK;` with capital letters, but in the actual Firestore it was saved as `sdk` with small letters, and when i was getting a User from Firestore i used `.toObject(User.class);` and that's probably where it was looking for `sdk` as it is in the database but found only `SDK`, so field didn't match, and it was left as `0`.

Conclusion: Don't use Capital letters when naming fields in Firestore, because it will change them to small ones in database and it will cause problems when trying to get document as Object Class back from Firestore.